# Formatting float time in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, floating-point

I have a datetime called dispatched_time which I am subtracting from Time.now which results in a float number ie: 302.332 which is a method called elapsed_time.  I need to figure out a way to take the value of that number and format it into a time in my view.  ie: 13:20.

I've tried to use elapsed_time.strftime("%H%M") but strftime won't process a float.

Can someone help me out with converting the float in seconds into a HH:MM format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `Time.at(elapsed_time).utc.strftime("%H:%M")`. This should give you the hours/minutes between the two times, created as if it were a time itself. Note that this may not work as well if there are more than 24 hours between the two times, in which case you would need to add a days parameter (`"%d"`) to the string passed to `strftime`.

Comment: This did what I was looking for.  I was doing all of the math in a method elapsed_time(seconds) and passing in the float and then splitting out to format.  The method you suggested is much easier and from what I can see so far, accurate.  Thanks William!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dotiw or ruby-duration gem. It may simplify things for you.

Comment: dotiw isn't what I'm looking for.  I can look at ruby-duration, but what I was really looking for was a way to calculate and split into a HH:MM format that I can use as a view helper.